# Java's Fillo plugin in node.js

Tags: node.js, excel

I wanted to fetch data using sql query from Excel file. Fillo library is there in java (https://codoid.com/fillo/) but I don't find similar library in node.js

Is there any simple way to achieve this using node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below fillo-js node module to query data from excel file.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fillo-js